# "Missing required argument $options" After migration from magento 1.9.2.4 to 2.1.3

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, magento2-migration-tool, core-config-data

[image]

When i'm trying to view my all migrated customers  then getting following error.

```
1 exception(s):
 Exception #0 (BadMethodCallException): Missing required argument $options    of Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Config.

Exception #0 (BadMethodCallException): Missing required argument $options of Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Config.
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(82): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Eav\\Mod...', Array, Array)
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Eav\\Mod...', Array)
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Validator/UniversalFactory.php(36): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Eav\\Mod...', Array)
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/AbstractAttribute.php(537): Magento\Framework\Validator\UniversalFactory->create('Magento\\Eav\\Mod...')
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AttributeMetadataConverter.php(66): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\AbstractAttribute->getSource()
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Metadata/CustomerMetadata.php(77): Magento\Customer\Model\AttributeMetadataConverter->createMetadataAttribute(Object(Magento\Customer\Model\Attribute))
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Metadata/CustomerMetadata.php(109): Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\CustomerMetadata->getAttributeMetadata('assigned_sales_...')
#7 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Metadata/CachedMetadata.php(82): Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\CustomerMetadata->getAllAttributesMetadata()
#8 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Ui/Component/Listing/AttributeRepository.php(66): Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\CachedMetadata->getAllAttributesMetadata()
#9 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Ui/Component/Listing/Columns.php(96): Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\AttributeRepository->getList()
#10 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(148): Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns->prepare()
#11 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(145): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->prepareComponent(Object(Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns))
#12 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(126): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->prepareComponent(Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Listing))
#13 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(93): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->generateComponent(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure), 'customer_listin...', Array, Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor))
#14 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#15 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(327): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#16 /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(89): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements()
#17 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(129): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements()
#18 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php(55): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#19 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#20 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(244): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#21 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(859): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build()
#22 /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(414): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock('menu')
#23 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/View/Result/Page.php(59): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getBlock('menu')
#24 /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Backend/Model/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page->setActiveMenu('Magento_Custome...')
#25 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index.php(26): Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->setActiveMenu('Magento_Custome...')
#26 /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Customer/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index->execute()
#27 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->execute()
#28 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(226): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#31 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Custome...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'adminAuthentica...')
#32 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#33 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#34 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Custome...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
#35 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33): Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#36 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#37 /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Customer/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#38 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#39 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#40 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#41 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#42 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#43 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#44 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'infortis_cgen_m...')
#45 /var/www/html/app/code/Infortis/Cgen/Plugin/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController.php(32): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#46 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Infortis\Cgen\Plugin\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#47 /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#48 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#49 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#50 /var/www/html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#51 {main}
```

**Update** 
After compile and removed generation folder:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Config::__construct() must be of the type array, null given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93 and defined in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Source/Config.php:26 
Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(93): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Config->__construct(NULL) 
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(88): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Eav\\Mod...', Array) 
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Eav\\Mod...', Array) 
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Validator/UniversalFactory.php(36): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Eav\\Mod...', Arr in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Source/Config.php on line 26
```

Comment: Clear `var/generation` folder & run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Comment: @Ankit I have done things as told by u. Error is not showing but when I'm trying to see customers it shows blank page. What should I do next?

Comment: Run command in order `php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush` & check for `var\log` for error logs `exception.log`

Comment: @Ankit After enable of error reporting it shows error.
I have updated question with that error.

Comment: Go to `magento\vendor` & delete all files & folders then run `composer install` on root

Comment: @Ankit I am unable to run composer command here.composer: command not found

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54988/discussion-between-ankit-shah-and-nitesh).

Comment: @Ankit I have found my solution and thanks for giving response buddy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to file 
        **var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Config.php**

Change to line 26 it will give detail description about error
        `public function __construct(array $options)` 
to 
         `public function __construct($options)`

Detail error description

```
    Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): No options found.
    #0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AttributeMetadataConverter.php(66): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Config->getAllOptions()
    #1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Metadata/CustomerMetadata.php(77): Magento\Customer\Model\AttributeMetadataConverter->createMetadataAttribute(Object(Magento\Customer\Model\Attribute))
    #2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Metadata/CustomerMetadata.php(109): Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\CustomerMetadata->getAttributeMetadata('assigned_sales_...')
    .
    .
    etc
```

Then from that description take

```
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AttributeMetadataConverter.php(66):
```

Go to above file enter following code before line 66

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($attribute->getData());
```

Then I get list of attribute_ids and see after which attribute_id error is comming take that one.

So I get attribute_id 150 who doesn't getting options.

So I'm not using that attribute_id so i have remove it..

Now my problem is solved and I can see my all migrated customers.

Please revert back all changes made in core files.

Comment: I tried the way which you said I too get that Id. In which table you have removed that attribute_id? which in your case is 150

Comment: I got the table its cuatomer_eav_attribute

Comment: Helli @Nitesh, file is not exist in this path  var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Config.php  ,Using Magento 2.2.4 version.Please share some code so that I can check it.I have same problem.

Comment: @akgola Yes, due to version change.

Comment: @akgola have you found file location i got same issue

Comment: @Pawankumar,Yes I found solution by deleting some attribute which was crated by third party module in Magento1.

Comment: In Magento 2.4.6 (migrated from 1.9.4.5) I had similar situation where Customers would crash; enabled developer mode which I saw AttributeMetadataConverter.php(100) and put simple var_export which was written to a file and VOILA! It was mailchimp attribute. Thank you for clue!

Answer (score 6):

I used this solution to solve the problem

- open phpmyadmin
- open 'customer_eav_attribute' table
- find out what attributes are imported looking at rows id

[image]

as you can see from id 40 there is a large gap before next id

- export a table backup ( so you can rollback if needed )
- delete attributes that are imported but not well applied

in my specific case deleting rows with id 146,285,286,+ has solved the problem

Comment: Worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was a custom select attribute that was missing source_model.

Steps to debug and fix:

1. xdebug - place a breakpoint vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php#L261 (throw new \BadMethodCallException)
2. go down through callstack and find the attribute_code
3. On db run the query to get attribute data "select * from eav_attribute where attribute_id = [YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_ID] \G"
4. Update source model of attribute (IF EMPTY) "update eav_attribute set source_model = 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table' where attribute_id = [YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_ID];"

Answer (score 1):

I solved in this way:

1. clean *generated/code/* folder
2. *php bin/magento setup:di:compile*

So, I have a new error type:

> Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
> Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Config::__construct() must
> be of the type array, null given ..

3. go to **eav_attribute** table, filtering for **entity_type_id = 1** (Customer entity) and look for the custom source model in **source_model** column
4. create the source model for Magento 2 (//Model/Attribute/

Answer (score 0):

for me I deleted only rows with the following conditions

- High ids that didn't run in sequence
- that is not system attribute
- that had 0 or null fields

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late in this party but if you get this issue then please try replacing `public function __construct(array $options)` with this `public function __construct(array $options = [])`

Happy Coding