# “Missing required argument $options” After migration from magento 1.9.2.4 to 2.1.6

Tags: magento-2.1, magento2-migration-tool

I am having the exact same problem as this issue- ["Missing required argument $options" After migration from magento 1.9.2.4 to 2.1.3](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/163287/missing-required-argument-options-after-migration-from-magento-1-9-2-4-to-2-1)

The solution talks about modifying this file- var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Config.php

That file is not there for me. I have looked and looked but can not find that file to try that solution. Does anyone know a workaround? or the location of that file? Did it move from 2.1.3 to 2.1.6?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem.

Try this:

Go to this file :

> /vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AttributeMetadataConverter.php

Add this line inside **createMetadataAttribute** function (after **if ($attribute->usesSource()) {**) :

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($attribute->getData());
```

Next, run setup:upgrade and open the customer grid in backend.
You need to follow after which attribute the error is thrown. 
Then, delete that attribute from **customer_eav_attribute** table.

You're done. :)

Comment: Nice solution  @PrithweemaD Thank You.