# Why am I getting this syntax error?

Tags: magento2, php

After migrating my site from M1 to M2 everything is working but the customer grid. I have followed this- ["Missing required argument $options" After migration from magento 1.9.2.4 to 2.1.3](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/163287/missing-required-argument-options-after-migration-from-magento-1-9-2-4-to-2-1)

Following those directions I add-

```
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($attribute->getData());
```

Above -

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getAttributeMetadata($attributeCode)
{
    /** @var AbstractAttribute $attribute */
    $attribute = $this->attributeMetadataDataProvider->getAttribute(self::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER, $attributeCode);
    if ($attribute && ($attributeCode === 'id' || $attribute->getId() !== null)) {
        $attributeMetadata = $this->attributeMetadataConverter->createMetadataAttribute($attribute);
        return $attributeMetadata;
    } else {
        throw new NoSuchEntityException(
            __(
                'No such entity with %fieldName = %fieldValue, %field2Name = %field2Value',
                [
                    'fieldName' => 'entityType',
                    'fieldValue' => self::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER,
                    'field2Name' => 'attributeCode',
                    'field2Value' => $attributeCode
                ]
            )
        );
```

So it looks like-

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($attribute->getData());
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getAttributeMetadata($attributeCode)
{
    /** @var AbstractAttribute $attribute */
    $attribute = $this->attributeMetadataDataProvider->getAttribute(self::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER, $attributeCode);
    if ($attribute && ($attributeCode === 'id' || $attribute->getId() !== null)) {
        $attributeMetadata = $this->attributeMetadataConverter->createMetadataAttribute($attribute);
        return $attributeMetadata;
    } else {
        throw new NoSuchEntityException(
            __(
                'No such entity with %fieldName = %fieldValue, %field2Name = %field2Value',
                [
                    'fieldName' => 'entityType',
                    'fieldValue' => self::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER,
                    'field2Name' => 'attributeCode',
                    'field2Value' => $attributeCode
                ]
            )
        );
    }
}
```

I then get-

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Metadata/CustomerMetadata.php on line 68
```

What am I failing to see?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. **ECHO** should be inside function. Not outside

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getAttributeMetadata($attributeCode)
{
    /** @var AbstractAttribute $attribute */
    $attribute = $this->attributeMetadataDataProvider->getAttribute(self::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER, $attributeCode);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($attribute->getData());

    if ($attribute && ($attributeCode === 'id' || $attribute->getId() !== null)) {
        $attributeMetadata = $this->attributeMetadataConverter->createMetadataAttribute($attribute);
        return $attributeMetadata;
    } else {
        throw new NoSuchEntityException(
            __(
                'No such entity with %fieldName = %fieldValue, %field2Name = %field2Value',
                [
                    'fieldName' => 'entityType',
                    'fieldValue' => self::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER,
                    'field2Name' => 'attributeCode',
                    'field2Value' => $attributeCode
                ]
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I now get a 404 error and it tried to send me here- http://magento.local/pub/errors/report.php?id=1160361407443&skin=default Any ideas?