# Magento 2.1.15: Problems with creating new customer (AttributeMetadataConverter.php)

Tags: magento2, customer-account

I try to create a new customer account with Magento 2.1.15 (via creating an order). 
After filling all required fields the following error occurred:

```
Error while saving the following order: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AttributeMetadataConverter.php on line 88
```

[image]

Also when I try to show the customer grid, the following error occurs:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AttributeMetadataConverter.php on line 88

Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AttributeMetadataConverter.php on line 88
#0 /html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AttributeMetadataConverter.php(88): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'Invalid argumen...', '/html/magento2/...', 88, Array)
#1 /html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Metadata/CustomerMetadata.php(77): Magento\Customer\Model\AttributeMetadataConverter->createMetadataAttribute(Object(Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute))
#2 /html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Metadata/CustomerMetadata.php(109): Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\CustomerMetadata->getAttributeMetadata('disable_auto_gr...')
#3 /html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Metadata/CachedMetadata.php(82): Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\CustomerMetadata->getAllAttributesMetadata()
#4 /html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-customer/Ui/Component/Listing/AttributeRepository.php(66): Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\CachedMetadata->getAllAttributesMetadata()
#5 /html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-customer/Ui/Component/Listing/Columns.php(96): Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\AttributeRepository->getList()
#6 /html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(148): Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns->prepare()
#7 /html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(145): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->prepareComponent(Object(Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns))
#8 /html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(126): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->prepareComponent(Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Listing))
#9 /html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(93): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->generateComponent(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure), 'customer_listin...', Array, Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor))
#10 /html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#11 /html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(327): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#12 /html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(129): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements()
#13 /html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php(55): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#14 /html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#15 /html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(244): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#16 /html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(860): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build()
#17 /html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/View/Result/Page.php(59): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock('menu')
#18 /html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index.php(26): Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page->setActiveMenu('Magento_Custome...')
#19 /html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index->execute()
#20 /html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(232): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 /html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 /html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#23 /html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Custome...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'weltpixel-owlca...')
#24 /html/magento2/app/code/WeltPixel/Backend/Plugin/Utility.php(76): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 /html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): WeltPixel\Backend\Plugin\Utility->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 /html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Custome...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'adminAuthentica...')
#27 /html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 /html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 /html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Custome...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
#30 /html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33): Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#31 /html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#32 /html/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Customer/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#33 /html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#34 /html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#35 /html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#36 /html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#37 /html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#38 /html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#39 /html/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#40 /html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#41 /html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#42 /html/magento2/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#43 {main}
```

There is obviously a problem with required fields. Does anybody know where should I start to find these (hidden) required fields? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found this post:
["Missing required argument $options" After migration from magento 1.9.2.4 to 2.1.3](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/163287/missing-required-argument-options-after-migration-from-magento-1-9-2-4-to-2-1)

and figured out the error with this code:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($attribute->getData());
```

in this file: AttributeMetadataConverter.php
With this I sorted out the ids with problems and modified them. It works.